# Allow only numbers and one dot in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following code with jQuery:

```
$('#from-amount').keypress(function(event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It does work, but i can use `.` at the start and paste (with the mouse and keyboard CMD+V) any string. How can i prevent `.` at the start and disable paste with keyboard and mouse?

Comment: You have JQuery available, right? Why you don't use Jquery maskedinput? you can use any pattern you want.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa because it's a different thing for a different task. I don't need a mask, i just won't allow user to type incorrect data.

Comment: could you please provide an example of the value you want?

Comment: Have you tried using regex on the value of the input?

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa, here's an example: https://en.utbs.ws/ in the field You give you got an input where do you put only numeric data and decimals.

Comment: `if (event.ctrlKey || (event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {`

Comment: @Jai that's won't work, it doesn't know `ctrlKey`

Comment: So, you can use Jquery maskMoney. `Remove the Currency Simbol`, no simbol for `thousands` and a dot for `decimal`.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa can you suggest not to using additional plugins?

Comment: Why not? Why waste energy on something that someone already wasted and is done? This is the core of the Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#from-amount').keypress(function(event) {
    if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
            $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).on('paste', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4rsv960t/1/

Comment: I need mouse event as well but its allow only numbers if i paste in text box, if its a text box automatically need to empty the text box